# C# settings form under settings menu

Tags: c#

Is there a way to display the projects settings in a form inside the application?

I have added a Menu Item called setting, Now when that is clicked I want a small form to popuo with the applications setings.

Is there a quick way to do this that just displays the settings as you would see them in Visual Studio? Or do I have to manually fetch the settings and display them?

If I need to manually do it. Which type of form must I use so that it will appear inside my main form?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll manually need to collect them and display them. To display on an area inside your main form you'll want to use a UserControl and place your created UserControl on your main form.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`PropertyGrid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx) control. It's the one what VS uses itself to edit properties of things (aka *settings*). Displaying things is pretty easy: add `PropertyGrid` to a form and assign object to it `propertyGrid.SelectedObject`. You will be able to see and edit *properties* of that object (in case of configuration settings this will be a configuration class instance I assume) almost right away! Tuning, adding localization, etc are not trivial tasks, but there are plenty of tutorials.

Otherwise, you could possibly use `TableLayoutPanel` with 2 columns: labels and respective texboxes (or other edit controls, to example, `NumbericUpDown` for `int` values), rows are autosized. But then you will have to add label and textbox for each setting yourself, as well as write some code to implement getting/setting of each configuration setting.